# Java : when do you want to customize the serialization process?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Under what circumstances and for what reasons should one consider customizing the `serialization` process? (The following methods are the methods that will be invoked by the `JVM`)

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out){
         //customize serialization
 }
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in){
         //customize de-serialization
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read A[dvanced Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/) from SUN

1. One common reason to override `readObject` and `writeObject` is to serialize the data for a superclass that is not `Serializable` itself.
2. Validate Streams
3. Encrypt serialized objects

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking some cases where you may want to control the serialization:

- When you want to encrypt and later decrypt the serialized data.
- You also may want the users or some other app to modify the serialized form of your objects so in that case you may want to write something more human friendly.
- If you're transmitting data over a network you may want to adapt the data so the program on the other side may understand it.

Those are the reasons I can think of right now.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of advantages of customized serialization is possibility to add transient fields (like inherited from other classes) into serialization process. You can do it like this

```
class NotMyClass implements Serializable {
    String login;
    transient String password;
    //...    
}

//I want to serialize also transient password field
class MyClass extends NotMyClass {

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("defaul serialization");
        out.defaultWriteObject();

        System.out.println("my serialization >>>> adding inherited transient value");
        out.writeObject(password);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("defaul deserialization");
        in.defaultReadObject();
        System.out.println("my deserialization <<<< reading stored transient value");
        password = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is when you want your sub-class to void `serialization` while the super-class is already `serializable`, and then you can just simply throw exception there in both methods in your sub-class.

I am not sure if there's any other specific reason or not.

Comment: Under what circumstances would that be advisable? I can't think why you'd want to void a method required by your implemented interfaces.

Comment: when you don't want to maintain the state of the super-classes which are automatically maintained by the serializable interface implementation

Comment: Again, under what circumstances is that advisable. If the super-class is serializable, presumably there is a reason for that? If you're negating expected functionality you're not coding to the stated signature's contract. That is asking for bugs and bad code.

Comment: Then what should we do if the parent is already serializable and you want to extend it without serializing it ?

Comment: Right; so my question is in what situations do you see that necessity?

Comment: You can have a collection with a mixture of parent and child object, and at some points you don't want the child object to be serialized  since serialization process can be costly especial child could be more specific (having additional variables) and lets say you just want to send list at the parent level over the network.

I personal never done it this way in practice, but this is just one of the reason that i can think of for customizing the process, and it's also recommended by SUN http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/ and in term of bad design it depends.

Comment: I post another question regarding to that. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125738/java-under-what-circumstance-would-you-want-your-child-class-to-avoid-serializ

Answer (score 0):

You might want to customize what you want to do at the time of a read or write-- you can add extra logging, you can perform computations, you might only want to read or write if certain conditions are met, etc.  Really, you can do anything Java allows.  For an example, see the section "Customize the Default Protocol" at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 0):

One other great reason is when you want to reduce the amount of data getting serialized. Take for example a `HashMap` with a capacity of say 1024. Let's say it has just 3 entries so far. Serializing an `Object` array of 1024 would be very wasteful, when all it needs to do is serialize the three entries.

On a separate note, if the objects you are serializing have references to non-serializable services, you would first mark those members as transient (to prevent serialization), but then use the `writeObject` to capture enough information so that `readObject` can re-establish the references upon de-serialization.