# Under what circumstance would you want your child class to avoid serializable if parent is serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

```
 class Parent implements Serializable{

      ........
 }

 class Child extends Parent{

      private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
            throw new NotSerializableException();
      }
      private void readObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
            throw new NotSerializableException();
      }

 }
```

The above code shows how child avoids `Serializable` if the parent is already implemented `Serializable`. It seems to be a bad design and confusing at some points, so I am wondering in what circumstance would you consider to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the parent is tagged as `Serializable` then every child should be serializable by design. Otherwise the bad design choice is not how you forbid serialization by throwing exceptions **but the fact that `Parent` shouldn't have been `Serializable`**.

Since there is no way to remove an interface implemented in a an ancestor class you have no choices: raising an exception is always better then serialize something which is not meant to be serialized, this would let you think everything went fine until something will go wrong with the serialized data. There is always a reason to forbid serialization: just adding a field in the child class which is not serializable is enough (unless you can use it as `transient` but this is not always possible, if the field contains critical information).

Comment: Then why SUN offers a way to avoid it ?

Comment: Because you don't have a way to prohibit this. `Serializable` is useful because it checks what can be serialized statically at compile time by using the strong type checker. If you tag something as `Serializable` then it's your duty to dynamically raise an exception from a child which is not serializable. You obtain the same result but just at runtime, which is always worse but at least you can handle it as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

The probable reason this might have happened is that the parent class may have originally been designed *not* as a parent class, but rather just normal serializable class. So later on, someone created a child class that wasn't serializable - that doesn't mean that the parent class has a "design flaw".

If you may have a particular child class that isn't `Serializable`, the only downside is a possible runtime exception if serialization is attempted. If you know that your non-serializable child class won't ever be serialized by your application, then there's no real problem.

Comment: The problem, I think, stems from the fact that while there isn't a general need for multiple inheritance, there are a few places where single inheritance isn't sufficient to define what should be allowable substitutions.  For example, if inheritable class `Foo` offers `protected` serialization methods (implying that it isn't publicly serializable, but derived classes might be), and `DerivedFoo` does likewise, and `Foo` and `DerivedFoo` have sealed serializable derivatives, it would be helpful to have a type which represented "a publicly-serializable `DerivedFoo`"...

Comment: ...and have that type be substitutable both for a [not-necessarily-publicly-serializable] `DerivedFoo` and for "a publicly-serializable `Foo`".  The only way for a publicly-serializable `DerivedFoo` to be substitutable for a publicly-serializable `Foo` is for it to inherit from that; the only non-serializable types that `DerivedFoo` could inherit from would be ancestors of `Foo` itself.

Comment: @supercat Right. It's almost like you need to make the absence of an interface "final", or have a `NotSerializable` interface that's honoured

Comment: There's more to it than that, since a reference of type `SerializableDerivedFoo` should be substitutable for either `DerivedFoo` or `SerializableFoo`, even though neither of those types is substitutable for the other.  One could use interfaces for those purposes, but that would require maintaining a hierarchy of interfaces in addition to the hierarchy of implementing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since Serializable is only a [tagging interface](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TagInterface), I don't see too much sense in the above construct. In Java there is no way to shadow this interface, which means that you are at the mercy of the code that is using your Child class. It may handle Serialization exceptions or may not.

One example when it handles such classes is when you've got some classes in a Java web container session, which gets persisted/restored to/from disk. In this case, Tomcat and other containers usually only give a warning but do not exit.